# Получить массив слов которые состоят из букв латинского или кириллического алфавита

Tags: jquery, preg_match, javascript, php

Добрый день.

есть стока

```
$str = '-stol.лампа.*112asd**ковер-карандаш*dasf//asdf-';
```

Как получить массив слов, которые состоят из букв латинского или кириллического алфавита, цифр и знака дефис (-)
то есть в итоге должно получить

```
-stol
лампа
112asd
ковер-карандаш
dasf
asdf-
```

я делаю вот так

```
$str.split(/[;,?/* ]/);
```

но писать все символы не круто..
Может есть какой - то по проще способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Для PHP**

**[Посмотреть пример регулярки](http://regex101.com/r/lN2aJ7/1)**

```
~([a-z\d-]++)|([а-яё\d-]++)~ui
```

**[Посмотреть пример кода](http://ideone.com/TPRBdj)**

```
$str = "-stol.лампа.112asdковер-карандашdasf//asdf-";
$pattern = "~[a-z\d-]++|[а-яё\d-]++~ui";
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => -stol
    [1] => лампа
    [2] => 112asd
    [3] => ковер-карандаш
    [4] => dasf
    [5] => asdf-
)
```

**Для javascript**

**[Посмотреть пример регулярки](http://regex101.com/r/lN2aJ7/2)**

```
/([a-z\d-]+)|([а-яё\d-]+)/gi
```

**[Посмотреть пример кода](http://jsfiddle.net/w1p8j2w8/1/)**

```
var str = '-stol.лампа.112asdковер-карандашdasf//asdf-';
var re = /[a-z\d-]+|[а-яё\d-]+/gi;
var result = str.match(re);
console.log(result);

// Array [ "-stol", "лампа", "112asd", "ковер-карандаш", "dasf", "asdf-" ]
```

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек)